# nasm win32 programming "undefined reference to..."

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, mingw, nasm

I'm trying to assemble and link a simple code with nasm and ld in mingw32 on windows xp
this is my code,

```
   extern _CopyFileA

section .data
    src  dd 'abc.txt',0
    dest dd 'xyz.txt',0
    false dd 'FALSE',0

section .text
    global  _WinMain@16
    _WinMain@16:


    push src
    push dest
    push false
    call _CopyFileA
    add esp, 12

    ret
```

I'm trying to use the `CopyFileA` function in `winbase.h`

assembling is working fine

```
nasm -f win32 copy.asm
```

but `ld` fails

```
ld file.obj -lkernel32
```

it says,

```
undefined reference to `CopyFileA'
```

Comment: Did you mean `_CopyFileA@12` ?

Comment: ya. just now I tried to link it with GoLink. It successfully linked. But the exe file execution crashes on the middle. file copies successfully though. How to avoid the crashing?

Comment: The Win32 API uses the `stdcall` calling convention, which means that you shouldn't clean up the stack after a function call. Also, you should probably end your program with a call to `ExitProcess` with 0 as the argument.

Comment: Wow. I never knew that. Thanks load. You just cured 3 hours of headache. :)
now It's working. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 API uses the [`stdcall` calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx), which means that the callee is responsible for cleaning up the stack. Therefore you should not do this yourself (i.e. there should be no `add esp, 12` after the call to `CopyFileA`).

Another effect of the `stdcall` calling convention is that the function names are *decorated* with an `@`-sign followed by the size of the function's arguments in bytes (as in `_WinMain@16`). The [`CopyFile` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes 3 arguments of 4 bytes each (12 bytes in total), so you should refer to it as (`_CopyFileA@12`).

Finally, you should end a Windows application with a call to [`ExitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: One more nit to pick. I doubt if "false" is supposed to be defined as the text "FALSE" - probably zero. (Are those parameters pushed in the correct order?)